# My keyboard writes by it self if I click sertain buttons

Tags: keyboard

So i recently built my first keyboard, and I lubed all the switches, but when I came to the stabs i didn't have anymore lube so I just assmbled the keyboard and I ordered more lube. when the lube came i dissasembled the keyboard and lubed the stabs.

Right after i assembled the the keyboard again some of the switches are automatically pressed. if i click eiter 6YHN they all actuate at the same time.

I have tried flashing my keyboard, turning on and off the computer and I tried using the keyboard on other computers, nothing worked. I think my pcb (DZ60rgb v2 hot swap pcb) is broken and I wonder if there is any way to fix this besides buying a new pcb.[In this picture i only pressed the 6 button and the switches actuated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qI3y9.png) Also sometimes when i press either one of 6yhn they don't work and sometimes the work

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You probably put too much lubrication on the key stabs and have shorted across the keys. When one key is pressed it is electrically shorting through the lubricant to the other keys.

Dismantle the keyboard, clean all the contacts and any surfaces between the keys using isopropyl alcohol, and reassemble.

Given the oily nature of the lubricant you may want to get some [proper PCB cleaner](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Ambersil-31560-PCB-Cleaner-400/dp/B014IPE2GU) and then rinse with isopropyl to get rid of remaining contaminants. You may end up having to rinse the entire key mechanisms to get rid of excess lubricant.

If you are going to apply lubricants then you want an absolute minimum on any surface. If you've applied a drop to every key stem them your keyboard will be swimming in lubricant. At most I would apply a drop to a cloth and then wipe the key stalk with the cloth, that is as much as should be needed.

Comment: isopropyl alcohol you will probably want to use 90% or higher for this purpose.

Comment: @Ramhound - maybe worth noting that isopropyl alcohol is flammable, toxic, and can cause eye and nose irritation.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - Mokubai isn't suggesting to use it to clean the PCB and ICs not poor it in their eyes or sniff it.  Seems like an unnecessary warning, since that warning, is literally on the bottle itself.

Comment: @Ramhound - we already have an over-oiled keyboard in the story.